# Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem

Tags: java

При изучении **Java** возникли некоторые затруднения.

**Идея**

Создать питомца который просто будет говорить, что он хочет, самым примитивным способом.

**Код:**

*Главный класс*

```
public class Progs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pet MyPet = new Pet();
        MyPet.says();
    }
}
```

*Побочные*

```
public class Pet {
    String[] all_says = {"Я хочу кушать","Я хочу пить","Все отлично"};
    public String says(String namePet, int needPet){
            String nd;
        if(needPet == 1){
            nd = all_says[1];
        }
        else{
            if(needPet == 2){
                nd = all_says[2];
            }
            else{
                nd = all_says[3];
            }   
        }

        System.out.println(namePet + ":" + nd);
    }
}

public class Fish{
    String name = "Karlson";
    int need = 1;
    Pet MyPet = new Pet();
    MyPet.says(name, need);
}
```

**Ошибка:**

Компилятор *Eclipse* выдает такую ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   The method says(String, int) in the type Pet is not applicable for the arguments()
>   at Progs.main(Progs.java:5)

И да, я знаю английский и здесь сказано, что типы не применимы для аргументов. Но я не понимаю, что уже не так?

Comment: а в чем вопрос то?
если мельком посмотреть в глаза бросается только этот участок 
if(needPet == 1){
            String nd = all_says[1];
        }
        else{
            if(needPet == 2){
                String nd = all_says[2];
            }
            else{
                String nd = all_says[3];
            }   
        }
Зачем тут 3 раза объявлять одну и туже переменную?

Comment: Прошу прощения, добавил вопрос

Comment: @DreamChild, боюсь, что так и есть)

Comment: @fleg, исправил)

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что похапе и JS очень терпимы к способностям и внимательности разработчика...но все же вызывать метод без аргументов, когда тот принимает аж целых два...это надо постараться

Comment: А зачем минусуем то? Вопрос, конечно, чайниковский, но минусовать не надо!

Comment: @DreamChild, Можно поинтересоваться зачем минус поставили? Проблему я ясно и четко пояснил, сразу предупредил, что только-только начал изучать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я конечно не силен в похапе, но думаю что топикстартёру надо вбить себе крепко-крепко в голову, что Java язык который жестко контролирует количество параметров функции/метода и не только кстати количество параметров, но также и тип выбрасываемого исключения (если есть таковое) и тип возвращаемого значения. Все это в совокупности именуется сигнатурой метода.

Теперь возвращаясь к вопросу. Как вам уже правильно ответили компилятор ругается на несовпадение декларированных типов к его вызову.

сигнатура вашего метода:

```
public String Pet.says(String namePet, int needPet)
```

А вы пытаетесь вызвать его как:

```
Pet.says();
```

Соответственно компилятор пытается найти в классе `Pet` метод `says()` без параметров и естественно не находит его там и оттуда и ругается.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор ругается на    MyPet.says(); в  public static void main
там должно быть два параметра типа String и int

Comment: @fleg, можно пример, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Pet MyPet = new Pet();
        MyPet.says("Karlson",2);

Comment: public class Progs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pet MyPet = new Pet();
        MyPet.says("Karlson",2); // было MyPet.says();
    }
}